# How to update the field value in multiple documents with help of another collection field value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Need to update the field value in one collection with help of another collection

Col1:

```
{ field1: 1 },
{ field1: 2 },
{ field1: 1 }
```

Col2:

```
{
  field1: 1,
  field2: 234
},
{
  field1: 2,
  field2: 545
},
{
  field1: 1,
  field2: 234
}
```

here if `coll1 field1 = col2 field1` then need to update `col1 field1: 234`

Col1 Output:

```
{ field1: 234 },
{ field1: 545 },
{ field1: 234 }
```

I have written a query but its updates only the first document only. Assists with this.

```
db.col1.find().forEach( function(doc1) {
  if(doc1.field1){
    var doc2 = dB.col2.findOne({"field1": doc1.field1});
    if(doc2) {
      doc1.field1 = doc2.field2;
      dB.col1.save(doc1);
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this lookup for that

```
db.col1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "col2",
      localField: "field1",
      foreignField: "field1",
      as: "joined_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      field1: { $arrayElemAt: ["$joined_docs.field2", 0] }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$field1"] }
    }
  }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
  db.col1.save(doc);
});
```

Comment: @muni if Answer is working then mark it as correct. So, other users get to know about correct answer.